# Force my preferences on user Chrome profile in Chrome web driver, add_experimental_option does not work on user chrome profile

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I can successfully launch my user Chrome profile on web driver but I cannot force my preferences on this user profile using add_experimental_option.

While the add_experimental_option work on default driver chrome instance but does not seems to work when I load my user chrome profile which I usually use on the system.

I tried using add_experimental_option to force my preferences like changing download directory, auto-download start, etc but these do not seem to work.

```
#intializing chrome
opts = Options()

#loading default profile
opts.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Jawad Ahmad 
Khan\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")

opts.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
 "download.default_directory": directoryToSave,#r'C:\Users\Jawad Ahmad 
  Khan\Desktop\webscraping\download/downloaded files',
  "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
```

I want to force my preferences on default Chrome profile launched using web driver.

Comment: How did you conclude that the `add_experimental_option` do not seem to work i.e not in effect?

Comment: I am runing the programme it loads my chrome profile with active logins bookmarks etc but not forcing add_experimental_options. Like e.g it does not start auto download as well as does not changes the download directory.

Comment: So, it seems your main issue is with _...start auto download..._ using _default Chrome profile_ adding the `experimental_option()`. Can you update the question with your code trials showing us where are you exactly stuck?

Comment: The above code is what i am using, web driver is opening my chrome with active logins and bookmarks but not forcing "download.prompt_for_download": False. @DebanjanB

Comment: What type of file are you trying to download? Is the website a public url? Can you share it?

Comment: https://www.who.int/intellectualproperty/documents/thereport/CIPIH23032006.pdf this is the link, i want it to start automatically not want browser to open a download prompt. @DebanjanB

Comment: Ummm, gimme some time to construct an answer for you.

Comment: Thanks alot, i will be waiting.